# Convert string to ndarray in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am reading a stream of data from an A-D converter via a socket from Python; the data come in as raw bytes. I want to format these bytes as int32 and place them into an ndarray. The read process looks something like this:

```
def datarecv():
    global msgbuf
    binlen = BURSTLEN + 4
    while len(msgbuf) < binlen:
        msgbuf = msgbuf + socket.recv(4096)
    reply = msgbuf[0:binlen]
    msgbuf = msgbuf[binlen:]
    # each recv comes with a 4 byte header that I throw away...
    return reply[4:]
```

The following is used successfully to write the received data to a file:

```
with open(filename, "wb') as f:
    bytesremaining = framesize
    for i in range(lines):
        f.write(datarecv()[0:min(linesize, bytesremaining)])
        bytesremaining -= linesize
```

I can then read back the file with something like this:

```
>>> data = numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype='int32')
>>> type(data)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So my data variable is the format I'm looking for, I.E.

```
>>> data[1:10]
array([4214234234, 2342342342, 2342342342, 34534535, 345345353, 5675757, 
      2142423424, 35334535, 35353535, 4754745754], dtype=int32)
```

** BUT ** I want to omit the intermediate step of writing to a file. After I read in the raw stream of data I want to make it an ndarray so that I can manipulate the data. I can change the line from

```
        f.write(datarecv()[0:min(linesize, bytesremaining)])
```

to

```
        bigbuf = bigbuf + datarecv()[0:min(linesize, bytesremaining)]
```

and then I end up with a big string. It's a string of raw bytes (not ASCII) which I have to convert to 32 bit integers. I'm hung up on this last step. I hope this makes sense what I'm asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `bigbuf` to an array with [`numpy.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)

For example:

```
In [21]: bigbuf = "\1\0\0\0\2\0\0\0"

In [22]: fromstring(bigbuf, dtype=np.int32)
Out[22]: array([1, 2], dtype=int32)
```